# Runtime URL modification of HLS streaming using iOS AVPlayer

Tags: ios, avplayer, http-live-streaming

We have stored recorded video in MS azure and for security purpose, MS azure needs to add a security token with the HLS URL.

For example if the actual URL is `http://samplevideo.m3u8` and the security token is `XXX` then, the URL that need to get the access of the video from azure is `http://samplevideo.m3u8?XXX`.

Also the `.ts` URLs contained in the `.m3u8` manifest file need to be altered.
For example, if the contained `.ts` URL is `PQR_vid_10.ts` then it needs to be converted to `PQR_vid_10.ts?XXX`

In android we are using Exo-player and it has a nice API that allows to modify each URL by giving a callback.
For example, we are using the below code for exo-player and it works very fine :

```java
private void buildHlsMediaSource() {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(testHlsUrl);
        HlsMediaSource hlsMediaSource =
                new HlsMediaSource.Factory(
                        new ResolvingDataSource.Factory(
                                new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(Util.getUserAgent(this, getString(R.string.app_name))),
                                (DataSpec dataSpec) -> dataSpec.withUri(resolveUri(dataSpec.uri))))
                        .createMediaSource(uri);
        player.prepare(hlsMediaSource);
        player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
        player.addListener(eventListener);
    }

 private Uri resolveUri(Uri uri) {
        String resultPath = uri.toString()+"?XXX";
        return Uri.parse(resultPath);
    }
```

But, we are unable to find a good/similar solution for iOS AVPlayer.
We have seen that, some SO answers suggests to use local proxy server to solve this. But we are not sure if this is the ultimate solution and any other better and straight forward solution is available or not.

So, can you please guide us for a possible easy/straight-forward solution or an example code snippet or any other documentation for this use case.

Thanks in advance